# Test Cases fail to satisfy

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just a beginner. I came across this question for which my code fails to satisfy all/most of the test cases.

Question:

> Given an array of numbers, find the number of non-empty sub-arrays in which the minimum and maximum element are identical.

Example:

> Input: Array = [1, 1, 3]
>
> Output: 4

Explanation:

> The required sub-arrays are [1], [1], [3], [1,1]

My solution:

> Sort the array and solve the problem.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testCases; i++){
        int arraySize = in.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[arraySize];
        for(int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++){
            array[j] = in.nextInt();
        }
        temp[i] = (findSubArrays(array));
}
for(int i = 0; i < testCases; i++){
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
}

private static int findSubArrays(int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);

   //Since each element can form a sub-array of its own
    int noOfSubArrays = array.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
        if(array[i] == array[i+1]){
            noOfSubArrays++;
        }
    }
    return noOfSubArrays;
}
```

Comment: Who said anything about sorting?

Comment: Concerning the sorting, I don't see it specified anywhere that this has to happen. Is it perhaps specified that the order of the numbers inside the sub-arrays is irrelevant? Or the opposite? Because if it's not stated, I would assume you're not allowed to change the order and also that the order inside each sub-array is important. Meaning [6,8,7] isn't considered the same as [6,7,8].

Comment: Do you have sample inputs and outputs, or somewhere to test?

Comment: I don't see why sorting shouldn't be done here. Yes, the order of numbers inside the sub-arrays are irrelevant. So once you sort it, you can just check the next element and get the answer.

Comment: @shmosel Yes. You can have it at https://codeshare.io/cCNQr. The number of test cases at a time is limited to 10 though.

Comment: @Raghav I don't see any test cases. I think I know what's wrong with your code, I'm just trying to confirm.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have any test cases. Please let me know whats wrong with the code. I'd be grateful.

Comment: Never mind my rambling, I was a bit confused. Deleted the additional questions as I realized those issues were made irrelevant by sorting.

Comment: Could you make your question a bit more specific, and outline what you've tried and where it's failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're sorting the array to keep begin points and end points adjacent so you don't need a nested traversal. That makes sense. The problem is that you're counting adjacent duplicates, but what you really need is `T(n)`, or the triangle number of consecutive duplicates. Consider a simple scenario:

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

Your algorithm returns `5`, but there are actually 6 subsets (by start & end index):

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 1
1, 2
2, 2
```

So let's update the algorithm to calculate the triangle number of each sequence:

```
private static int findSubArrays(int... array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);

    int sequenceCount = 0;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {
        if (i == array.length || (i > 0 && array[i] != array[i - 1])) {
            total += triangle(sequenceCount);
            sequenceCount = 0;
        }
        sequenceCount++;
    }
    return total;
}

private static int triangle(int n) {
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}
```

Now calling `findSubArrays(1, 1, 1)` returns `6` and `findSubArrays(1, 1, 3)` returns `4`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shmosel. I really appreciate your help. And my algorithm returns 5 and not 2. Just saying. Nothing personal :)

Comment: How did you hit on that triangle function? I've been thinking for hours but to no good.

Comment: @Raghav Look up the handshake problem. This is very similar.